# fiddler autoresponder not working

Tags: fiddler, auto-responder

I added a rule (flash file), specified the new flash file I want fiddler to respond with (use instead of the browser one). I've cleared my browser cache, and every time I play the stream, the browser flash file is captured again (instead of auto-responding) with the one saved already!!!

It used to work just fine, but now it appears as if the auto-responder (although checked) is not working at all...it's just a pass-through!!!

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the forum post where you asked the same question

There are three possibilities:

1> The AutoResponder itself is disabled (checkbox at the top)
2> The AutoResponder rule is disabled (checkbox at the left of the rule)
3> The rule you've written doesn't match the target request's URL.

Sharing a screenshot of Fiddler might help me tell you which problem you're encountering.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, and I solved it by enabling decryption of HTTPS traffic.
You can do this by going to **Tools > Options >** , then check **Decrypt HTTPS Traffic**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On the top of the list EricLaw gave in the previous answer, I add a new one:

- You need to ensure your Fidler has the "Capturing Traffic" mode enabled. Either press F12 or go to "File" -> "Capture Traffic" and make sure you have a "Capturing.." icon on your left bottom corner.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I drag-dropped from the left, "main", window into the autoresponder so the "request matches..." column auto-populated.  As a sanity check I unchecked "unmatched requests passthrough" to ensure that the match rule was indeed picking it up.  If it hadn't nothing would appear in the main window at all. But it did appear so the rule was matching.

The issue with Fiddler is in the "then respond with..." column.  Right-click for "Edit Response...", edit the response in the popup window of tabs, press Save, close the box.

When you retry your URL, your edited response isn't returned. Fiddler returns the original response. Even if you Edit Response again, it'll show what you typed in, but it never actually returns it.

To fix, you have to save the intended response to a file on your hard drive and edit it there.